# how to call a component by onclick in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi guys I am trying to call my child component: `MakeQuizePage` in  my parent component: 'StartPage'
but not works my code :

```
 import MakeQuizePage from './makeQuizePage';

function StartPage() {
    return (
        <>
            <h1 className=" my-5   fs-1 text-danger text-center  ">کی از همه خبیث تره</h1>  ;
            <div className="my-5 text-center">
                <button onClick={nextPage} className="shadow btn  p-4 btn-lg col-3 text-center">start  </button>
            </div>
        </>
    )
    function nextPage() {
        return (<MakeQuizePage />)
    }
}
export default StartPage;
```

```
 and this is my child component: MakeQuizePage (jsx)
```

```
import { useState } from "react";
const MakeQuizePage = () => {
    const [pageCount, setPageCount] = useState(0);
    const questionAndRezults = [
        [
            'asa'
        ],
        [
            'akks'
        ]
    ];

    return (
        <>
            <p className='text-center'>{questionAndRezults[pageCount][0]}</p>
            {questionAndRezults[pageCount].slice(1).map((p, index) => (
                <>
                    <p className='text-center'>{questionAndRezults[pageCount].slice(1)[index]}</p>
                    <button className="form-check-input" type="radio"></button>
                </>
            ))}
        </>
    )
    const nextPageMaker = function nextPage() {
        setPageCount(
            pageCount + 1);
        console.log(pageCount)
    }
}
export default MakeQuizePage;
```

```
///when I tested by a simple function this onclick work, but not working by Codes above
```

Comment: How can react know where to place `<MakeQuizePage/>` when you call `nextPage()`?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your product requirements

1. You want `MakeQuizePage` to be an independent page with its own URL that people can directly access it

OR

2. `MakeQuizePage` and `StartPage` share the same URL

For #1, you should consider using [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial) or [NextJS](https://nextjs.org/) as they provide you a routing mechanism for pages with different URLs

For #2, the `onClick` callback should control what is visible instead of returning `MakeQuizePage`

A high level code could look like this

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import MakeQuizePage from './makeQuizePage';

function StartPage() {
  // useState to create a visibility flag
  const [isQuizePageVisible, setIsQuizePageVisible] = useState(false)

  const onClickHandler = () => {
    // Set the visibility flag to true when the button is clicked
    setIsQuizePageVisible(true)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1 className=" my-5   fs-1 text-danger text-center  ">کی از همه خبیث تره</h1>  ;
      <div className="my-5 text-center">
        {/* When button is clicked, call the `onClickHandler` defined above */}
        <button onClick={onClickHandler} className="shadow btn  p-4 btn-lg col-3 text-center">start  </button>

        {/* When the flag is true, the page will be shown */}
        {isQuizePageVisible && <MakeQuizePage />}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default StartPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the nextPage nested in the StartPage component,you can use display to control the visiability of the nextPage,like below:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import MakeQuizePage from "./makeQuizePage";

function StartPage() {
  const [nextPageView, setnextPageVeiw] = useState("none");
  return (
    <>
      <h1 className=" my-5   fs-1 text-danger text-center  ">
        کی از همه خبیث تره
      </h1>{" "}
      ;
      <div className="my-5 text-center">
        <button
          onClick={nextPage}
          className="shadow btn  p-4 btn-lg col-3 text-center"
        >
          start{" "}
        </button>
        <div style={{ display: nextPageView }}>
          <MakeQuizePage />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
  function nextPage() {
    return setnextPageVeiw("block");
  }
}
export default StartPage;
```

If you only want to jump to next page and replace startpage,you can do the follwing:
npm install react-router-dom@6.9.0;

```
// in App.js
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";

import StartPage from "./StartPage";
import MakeQuizePage from "./MakeQuizePage";

import "./styles.css";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <StartPage />
  },
  {
    path: "next",
    element: <MakeQuizePage />
  }
]);

const App = () => <RouterProvider router={router} />;

export default App;
```

```
// in StartPage.js
import { useState } from "react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import MakeQuizePage from "./MakeQuizePage";

function StartPage() {
  const [nextPageView, setNextPageVeiw] = useState("none");
  return (
    <>
      <p>startpage</p>
      <h1 className=" my-5   fs-1 text-danger text-center  ">
        کی از همه خبیث تره
      </h1>{" "}
      ;
      <div className="my-5 text-center">
        <button
          onClick={nextPage}
          className="shadow btn  p-4 btn-lg col-3 text-center"
        >
          start{" "}
        </button>
      </div>
      {/* <div style={{ display: nextPageView }}>
        <MakeQuizePage />
      </div> */}
      {nextPageView === "block" && <Navigate to="next" replace={true} />}
    </>
  );
  function nextPage() {
    const nextState = nextPageView === "none" ? "block" : "none";
    return setNextPageVeiw(nextState);
  }
}
export default StartPage;
```

Here is a  [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-reouter-ans-pxbige) containing the code above

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal using setState, here is a snippet of the Parent Component Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import MakeQuizePage from './MakeQuizePage';
function StartPage() {
  const [showMakeQuiz, setShowMakeQuiz] = React.useState(false);

  function handleClick() {
    setShowMakeQuiz(true);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to the Start Page</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Start Quiz</button>
      {showMakeQuiz && <MakeQuizePage />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default StartPage;
```

This way whenever user click the button the child component will be displayed.
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score -2):

You said your file is `MakeQuizePage.jsx` . and your importing

```
import MakeQuizePage from './makeQuizePage';
```

if your folder is MakeQuizePage.jsx try importing like this

```
import MakeQuizePage from './MakeQuizePage';
```

the error is in folder name.
you can check the also check what is the error in your browser console